# LDAP connection throwing SunCertPathBuilderException, on alternate connections on linux

Tags: java, linux, ssl, ldap

I am using the following test code to connect to ldap server. Its working fine on windows, but on linux it connects when I run the program on the first attempt and then on second it throws the exception and on third attempt it connects successfully and so on (ie success on odd executions, failure on even ones) which is strange. I have added the ssl certificate in java default keystore. I am using java 1.8_161. keystore location : "/usr/java/jre1.8.0_161/lib/security/cacerts". I am executing the code block as jar file.

```
        Hashtable<String, String> ldapContextDetails = new Hashtable<>();
        ldapContextDetails.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        ldapContextDetails.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
        ldapContextDetails.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "username");
        ldapContextDetails.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "password");
        ldapContextDetails.put(Context.REFERRAL, "follow");
        ldapContextDetails.put("com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.timeout", "10000");
        ldapContextDetails.put(Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL, "ssl");

        String providerUrl =  "ldap://domain1.com:636/";
        ldapContextDetails.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, providerUrl);
        InitialLdapContext ldapContext;
        try {
            ldapContext = new InitialLdapContext(ldapContextDetails, null);
            System.out.println("connected");
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**Update:**
I enabled the ssl logs and found that in failing case server is establishing via TLSv1.2 :
  
`1118 main, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 1607
1119 *** ServerHello, TLSv1.2`
and in case of success via TLSv1:

`1200 main, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 2927
  1201 *** ServerHello, TLSv1`

Also I have checked that the certificate had expired, so does TLSv1.2 does not support but TLSv1 supports this? . Also is the behavior of selecting the TLS protocal done in alternate for every connection?

Comment: It sounds like you have 2 LDAP servers behind a load-balancer, not only one.

Comment: Yes I checked and found out that there were two LDAP servers and certificate of only one was added.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, there were 2 LDAP servers behind it and certificate of both had to be added as pointed by @Eugène Adell.